# Native iOS music player pauses when playing HTML5 audio

Tags: ios, html5-audio, background-music

My Google-Fu has failed me.

Is it possible for the native iOS music player to NOT pause when playing a sound from within an HTML5 web app?  I know native apps don't have this problem but am struggling with HTML5.

(Using iOS6).

Answer (score 0):

Please, see this topic: [iPod - Let the native music app to play sound in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635496/ipod-let-the-native-music-app-to-play-sound-in-background). I've used the same approach to allow iPod music playback while game playing with embedded ambients and sounds.

Comment: That approach is for native apps though.  I am using the <audio> tag in an HTML5 app.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry. Thought, that you are using UIWebView for html5 purposes.